# Auto Date created and Last Modifier Google Sheet App scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp, last-modified, datecreated

Im tried complete my inventory sheet with a function date created and last modifier via a [tutorial Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=548dD3iXetg&t=2s), im reading comment, many guys have trouble like me, i think if found the way solve this issue, its will help many, thank in advance any help.

Im not a developer or some guys have knowledge about code. Shame is my english also not good. Forgive me, this is my first topic in a biggest dev community, hope i have welcome.

I have some problem its not working as i want in some case like. My test spreadsheet [is here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IpGwvkiq-_Az5rHhUIxEnAEhluWNyUMimUDLLgqbTkU/edit?usp=sharing)

1. Copy paste a lot row, its dont work.
2. When pull a cell, array, its just work with first row.
3. Instant display time when a new row created also fill not yet.
4. Both time still display when im delete cell to empty a row.

```
function onEdit(e) {

  addTimestamp(e);

}

function addTimestamp(e){
  //variables
  var startRow = 3;
  var targetColumn = 1;
  var ws = "DATABASE";

  //get modified row and column
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();

  if(col === targetColumn && row >= startRow && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === ws){

    var currentDate = new Date();

    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,23).setValue(currentDate);
    if(e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,22).getValue()==""){
      e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,22).setValue(currentDate);
    } // END IF check if date created exists
  } // END IF check column, row, worksheet
} //END function add Timestamp
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

And please note that you cannot run this function from the script editor without using an intermediate function to build and supply the event object.  Instead just save it and edit the "DATABASE" sheet and use e.source.toast() or Logger.log() to debug it.  The onEdit trigger will supply the event object.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast("Entry");
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "DATABASE" && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.range.rowStart > 2) {
    e.source.toast("Flag1");
    let dt = new Date();
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,23).setValue(dt);
    if(sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,22).getValue() == "") {
      e.source.toast("Flag2");
      sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 22).setValue(dt);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Anyway thank you but your code still unsolved my listing issue, its still not work with interact like copy paste a bulk, pull down a cell.